# Run Bash Script in New Process Tree

Tags: linux, bash

I am working with a complex bash script that performs various operations and the restarts the Linux (CentOS 6) server on which it was run. This script is invoked from a couple of different places. *I am looking for a way to initiate execution of this complex bash script in a new process tree*.

I put together the following text diagram to illustrate the scenario:

```
a_process_that_calls_script
 \_ subshells/processes/commands_of_calling_process
...
bash_script
 \_ subshells/commands/other_scripts_called
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potential duplicate: [How can I launch a new process that is NOT a child of the original process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20338162/how-can-i-launch-a-new-process-that-is-not-a-child-of-the-original-process)

If you have a process invoke the script as a grandchild process, and then the child exits, the grandchild will become a child of the init process.