# Using system("./some_program"), how to prevent termination of parent process when "some_program" dies?

Tags: c++, linux

Under Linux, I have a C++ code that calls an external program (a compiled Fortran program). This external program sometimes aborts (i.e. "STOP" is issued in its code when some conditions are met) which is OK. BUT: the external program termination also kills the parent C++ program. 
I would like the C++ code to continue running, even when the external program stops execution normally or abnormally.

The C++ "parent" program executes the external program with system("./external_program").

[Note: Yes, I'm aware that using system() has security issues, but currently it's irrelevant to me]

Thanks

General Info: The C++ program uses MPI for parallel execution and launches N parallel instances of the external program - each one in its own directory.

The error message upon the termination of both programs:
Primary job terminated normally, but 1 process returned non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.

mpirun noticed that process rank 18 with PID 0 on node Ashton exited on signal 6 (Aborted).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I think this is realated: [How can I launch a new process that is NOT a child of the original process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20338162/691711)

Answer (score 1):

Good news: problem solved!
Following @Ted Lyngmo advice, I basically wrote 2 new codes that suppose to mimic the operation of the original 2 codes which are too big to extract a minimal reproducible example. Surprisingly, the issue wasn't present in the new example! This of course suggested me that the reason the main program terminated was not the abort signal in the external program.

Solution:
To put it short, I launched gdb and carefully analyzed the original code in serial mode after making sure I get a reproducible error (debugging with MPI is beyond me). I found out that the program tried to access an uninitialized vector which caused 'out_of_range' errors and parent program exited immediately. The reason this confused me is that, this uninitialization happens when the external program aborts - this is why I thought it is related to the actual termination process of the external program, whereas the issue was much much simpler.

Thanks guys!